# Correct implementation of utility classes [Swift]

Tags: swift, xcode6

I am in the process of cleaning up my code as my `TableViewController` class has become rather full and long. To clean up the code, I would like to create a number of utility classes that provide methods for the `TableViewController`. These methods/functions, in my current implementation, are able to change variables in the main `TableViewController`. Here is an example of my current setup:

```
class FooImplementation: NSObject {
    var viewController: Foo

    init(viewController: TableViewController) {
        self.viewController = viewController
    }
}

class FooUtility1: FooImplementation {
    // Methods
}

class FooUtility2: FooImplementation {
    // Methods
}

class Foo: TableViewController {
    var fooUtility1: FooUtility1
    var fooUtility2: FooUtility2

    override viewDidLoad() {
        fooUtlity1 = FooUtility1(self)
        fooUtlity2 = FooUtility2(self)
    }

    // Use of the methods...
}
```

Is there a better/universally defined way of creating and using these classes? And can these classes be combined into one `Utility` class that has access to all of the methods `FooUtility1` and `FooUtility2` provide?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't consider adding utility classes a good design pattern, for at least the following reasons:

- they can change the internal status of the view controller
- you have to "upgrade" member properties to internal or public when they are private by nature

Of course I don't know what kind of behaviors you want to move from view controllers to the utility classes - my advice is to use one or more of the following:

- create view controller extensions
- create your own set of base view controllers, inherited from `UIViewController`, to be used as super classes for your final view controllers
- move some logic to external classes, but use the delegation pattern to interact

The second case is one I frequently use, and the 3rd is one I've applied to my latest project, using better separation of concerns by implementing for each view to be displayed:

- a view controller, responsible of managing (but not displaying) the view, and handling events received from its view(s)
- a data source, responsible of providing the data to be displayed in the view, along with methods to add/delete/update if needed
- a (hierarchy of) view, implemented in a separate class in its own xib file.

It makes development a little more complicated, but in the end I have a light view controller, and a view that is responsible of displaying data, handling events and forwarding them to the view controller.

Note that this is not **the solution**, just **one possible solution**. There are several variables to take into account, for sure what you want to move from the view controller, and I think also personal preference.

Comment: The utility classes, for example, one provides a list of methods which help to create and set the text in the cells. Another implements the data retrieval for the view controller and updates the table view accordingly etc. What would your advice be specifically for these, based on your comments above? thanks again

Comment: cells: I usually pass data to the cell and let it render - I do in cellForRowAtIndexPath. That makes the cell reusable

Comment: data retrieval: I never implement that in a view controller - instead I have several `UserManager`, `PostManager`, etc. responsible of retrieving data - separation of concerns is the key